# Creating All-Day Events Using Android Calendar Provider

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, android-calendar

I would like my app to insert all day events into the calendar. I started off with the example given at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html. To make it all-day, I add the `ALL_DAY` content value and set the time zone to UTC. I end up with the folowing code:

```
long calID = 3;
long startMillis = 0; 
long endMillis = 0;     
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(2012, 9, 14, 7, 30);
startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(2012, 9, 14, 8, 45);
endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
values.put(Events.ALL_DAY, 1)
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
values.put(Events.TITLE, "Jazzercise");
values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group workout");
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "UTC");
Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Now, this actually does the job but the `DTEND` time seems redundant and setting start and end times meaningless when really only the date is needed. When I remove the `DTEND` value, I get an exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DTEND and DURATION cannot both be null for an event.`. What would be the proper values? Just arbitrary as above or could/should this actually be done with meaningful information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DTEND` is not redundant as it specifies the end of the event. *all-day* doesn't mean that it's just one day long. It could span any number of days. *all-day* means start and end of the event have no time component. In particular, the event always begins when the day begins, no matter in which time zone you're actually located at that time. A common example is your birthday. You usually celebrate it on a specific calendar day, no matter where exactly you are.

Note that in Android's calendar database `DTSTART` and `DTEND` should represent midnight of that specific day in UTC.

So a better way of deriving the start and end dates would be:

```
TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance(utc);
// set all values to 0
beginTime.clear();
beginTime.set(2012, 9, 14);
startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();

Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance(utc);
// the event ends right before the next day begins
endTime.clear();
endTime.set(2012, 9, 15);
endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();
```

Also note that `DTEND` is non-inclusive (it points to the first moment after the event). For a one day all-day event that means, `DTEND` is the start of the next day.

Another way of determining the end of the event is by adding the duration of the event to `DTSTART` like so:

```
// Add the duration of 1 day to startMillis to get the end
endMillis = startMillis + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1);
```

The result is the same as above.

Be aware that this is how to create non-recurring events. If you create a recurring event you must not set `DTEND` but `DURATION`.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Replace CalendarContract.Events.DTEND with [CalendarContract.Events.DURATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html?#DURATION)

The second param format see [RFC5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.2.5)

```
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DURATION,  "PT1D");
```

Do not use DTEND when you are using DURATION, or there will throw an exception: Cannot have both DTEND and DURATION in an event

Comment: Thanks. Useful additional info but not really answering the question.